# Calculate derivative: $\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\sin(x)$

Tags: derivatives, fractional-calculus, trigonometry

Is it possible to "calculate" / simplify this expression? If it is, how can it be done?

$$
\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\sin(x)
$$

for

$
\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}
$

I think it is equal to $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\beta \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)$, but i am absolutely not sure if this is true.

Thank you,

Best regards

Kevin

-edit-

Here is the desription how i got my result (which maybe helps to verify it):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differintegral#A_selection_of_basic_formul.C3.A6
$$\Rightarrow \frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\sin(x)=\sin(x+\alpha\frac{\pi}{2})$$

Because $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(ax)=a^nf^{\left(n\right)}(ax), n\in \mathbb{N}$ i think $\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(ax)=a^\alpha f^{\left(\alpha\right)}(ax), \alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is also true. Unfortunately i'm not sure if this is true.

Because $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}f(x+a)=f^{\left(n\right)}(x+a), n\in\mathbb{N}$ is true, i also hope that $\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x+a)=f^{\left(\alpha\right)}(x+a), \alpha\in\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ is true.

With these new rules the expression can be calculated:
$$
\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}\sin(x)
$$
$$
=\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\sin(x+\alpha\frac{\pi}{2})
$$
$$
=\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\alpha+\frac{2}{\pi}x\right))
$$
This is just a shifted $\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma)$.
$$
\gamma=\alpha+\frac{2}{\pi}x
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\frac{d^\beta}{d\alpha^\beta}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma)
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\beta}\sin^{\left(\beta\right)}(\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma)
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\beta}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\gamma+\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^{\beta}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\alpha+\frac{2}{\pi}x\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\beta)
$$
$$
=\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^\beta \sin\left(x+\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\alpha+\beta\right)\right)
$$

Comment: What is your definition of the fractional derivatives? With the Fourier interpretation $\frac{d^\alpha}{dx^\alpha}f(x) \equiv \mathcal{F}^{-1}[(i\omega)^\alpha\mathcal{F}[f]]$ (and ignoring possible branch issues of the complex logarithm) one gets something that looks alot like the answer you got.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not too good with fractional calculus, but i tried to get the solution with some rules i found in google. But do the different methods to do fractional calculus produce different results? I hoped they all end with the same expression.

Comment: That is probably the case, but I'm not that familiar with this subject. The reason I asked is so that people can answer in a language you understand. It might be a good idea to add your own derivation (or a sketch of it) to the question.

Answer (score 1):

For shorthand, $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}=D^n_x$

Consider $D^n_xe^{cx}=c^ne^{cx}$.  Seems true through induction.

Now, have $c=i$, and we can use Euler's formula.

$$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+i\sin(x)$$

$$D^n_xe^{ix}=i^ne^{ix}=e^{i(x+\frac{n\pi}{2})}=\cos(x+\frac{n\pi}2)+i\sin(x+\frac{n\pi}2)$$

Of course, you could have some doubt in this, since this not directly imply the fractional derivative of the trig functions, but we can work our way there.

More directly, consider $\sin(x)=\frac{e^{ix}-e^{ix}}{2i}$ and differentiate like so

$$D^n_x\sin(x)=D^n_x\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}=\frac{i^ne^{ix}-(-i)^ne^{-ix}}{2i}$$

$$=\frac{e^{i(x+\frac{n\pi}2)}-e^{-i(x+\frac{n\pi}2)}}{2i}$$

$$=\sin(x+\frac{n\pi}2)$$

I would consider that the easiest way to showing it, and then the rest you've done right.